# know to truncate a dataset after finding the maximum

Tags: matlab

I have a data set from experimental data.
I am can find the position of the maximum value, but I need to find a way to:
after the maximum is found, truncate dataset, or make the rest of the series 0.
I am using the following could but is not working.

I make the `mod_data_1` as my new dataset, that goes from `N=1` to `N_max`.

```
mod_data_1 = data_1;


N_max = find(data_1(:,2) == max(data_1(:,2)));
N_max(1);

for N=1;size (data_1,2);
 if data_1(N,1) > N_max;
   mod_data_1 (N,:)=0;
 end
end
mod_data_1(all(mod_data_1==0,1),:) = []
```

Comment: Can you clarify the dimensionality/size of your data?  Also, you are searching for the max value in the second column, then you simply want to chop all rows after that? Or do you want to somehow search for that max value in the first column? It's not clear from your code. Thanks.

Comment: Also, does the first column of `data_1` simply contain the row number?

Comment: I only have flow (1) and pressure(2). when finding maximum flow truncate or save new dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `find(D == max(D))` approach use the second output of `max`:

```
[~,N_max] = max(data_1(:,2));
```

Conveniently, this returns the index of the *first* occurrence of the maximum value:

> If the values along the first non-singleton dimension contain more than one maximal element, the index of the first one is returned.

---

Then, to truncate:

```
data(N_max+1:end,:) = [];
```

Or if you want to set to zero, instead do `data(N_max+1:end,:) = 0;`.

Or to make a copy instead of truncating original:

```
mod_data_1 = data(1:N_max,:);
```

---

Regarding your code, note that `for N=1:size(data_1,2)` loops over the number of columns, so that is not suitable to be indexed by `data_1(N,1)`. To loop over rows, you want `size(data_1,1)`. However, don't loop. You can do this all without loops using indexing.

Comment: thanks chappjc, this code is working ok. when combining the code i can plot exactly what i want. super thanks

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have numerous errors in your code. If you want to set all values less than your maximum value to 0, `if data_1(N,1) > N_max` should be `if data_1(N,1) < N_max`. Also you are using semicolons wrong in your loops. See the corrected code below:

```
mod_data_1 = data_1; 
N_max = find(data_1(:,2) == max(data_1(:,2)));
N_max(1);

for N=1:size(data_1,2)
 if data_1(N,1) < N_max
   mod_data_1 (N,:)=0;
 end
end
mod_data_1(all(mod_data_1==0,1),:) = []
```